# Adding the prefab Delete comments to the regular Delete link

Tags: feature-request, comments, vote-to-delete

When one goes into Review > Low Quality Posts and decided to delete an answer they are given a pop-up window of a bunch of pre-fabricated comments to post along with the delete vote.

Alot of the time i tend to spot answers that need to be deleted (most time it's ment to be a comment) before they get picked up in the view que and after i made my delete vote they wouldn't appear in the que for me. the alternative is to keep refreshing the review pages waiting for the ques to be updated but kind seems redundant when i can act right now (in these situations)

My suggestion is that the pop-up allowing you to select one of the pre-fab delete comments should also be added to the regular delete link.

Comment: You may find yourself interested in http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se, the original source of those same auto-comments.